# PolynomialFeatures with degree 5 to fit a model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a scatter of X and y:

[image]

After fit to linear regression in sklearn with polynomial features degree 5:

```
degree = 5
X_poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree).fit_transform(X.reshape(-1, 1))
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X_poly, y)
```

Then I have this plot:

[image]

As you can see, `predict[0]` is larger than `y[0]` a lot. How to fix this?

Comment: It will be really difficult to use a polynomial/linear algorithm to predict it since the polynom change drastly from `y[0]` to `y[1]`. it's looks that `y[0]` influence badly on the model. I think if it's possible to remove `y[0]` from the model that's will be the best solution.

Comment: I don't think this is a programming problem. The fit runs as it should be minimize the error and you get the best fit line as soon in blue. If you want the line to go through y[0], it's not longer a linear model right

Comment: @StupidWolf yes this is not a programming problem, I just want to ask how I can modify the curve by maybe, delete some points to let it go through y[0]

Comment: Deleting data to fit the answer you want is not right.